# How CPU set up data and stack cached as temporary memory for the PEI phase?

Tags: cpu, firmware

I would to understand what electronically exactly happens when I set `Disable USB ports` from BIOS.
Where this value is set ? in ROM, CMOS, NVRAM ?

This is strange because I can access on Shell UEFI via Serial Port

I find also this scheme

[image]

**[Security (SEC) Phase]**
The code in the SEC phase is executed during power on. Its main functions are to:

> •  set up data and stack cached as temporary memory for the PEI phase 
>   •  serve as a root of trust in the system 
>   •  hand off information to the PEI Foundation 
>   •  discover and pass control to the PEI Phase 
>   It is during this phase that the bootstrap processor (BSP) switches to protected mode and the microcode patch update is performed on all the CPUs.

**The PEI phase** is describe well [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/unified-extensible-firmware-interface/efi-pei-cis-v091.html)

What is this `stack cached as temporary memory` ? Is cpu cache ?

I don't understand how cpu make this, what logic layer is involved ?

So.. value in BIOS UEFI `Usb: disabled` is saved in ROM but I see that value ***is generated*** after cpu reset so when cpu impulse *entering* in UEFI Rom and 'read' the logic state after it 'move' the bits in cpu cache ?
But this is possible only if you have a *clock signal* (one oscillator make this periodic sync signal). What happens if I start to modulate this clock signal with a function generator by inserting into the circuit ?

You can shed light on electronic logic process?

Comment: ROM is READ ONLY memory, you cannot change what is tored in it. CMOS is a technology, so technically nope. In PC environenment there is a CMOS tech based violative storage part which stores BIOS settings. It could be stored there is you have an old motherboard with BIOS firmware. NVRAM is more or less the same but for systems with EFI firmware.

Comment: Is `read only` only when there is a signal, which feeds the circuit with current but you can modulate this current. There is no `data` stored in ROM because you can't *flash*, *dump*, *read* if you have not this supply voltage at 50-60Hz and 220V. the electronic circuit only performs the logical-electric combination to represent the information on the monitor but inside ROM there is only flip flops and transistors electrically charged. `data` you refer the binary digit rappresentation using logic, I speak what function I can generate. If I change current function you read different data on

Comment: monitor, information is only a manifestation but not depends only from 'code' or electronical combination, this happens because you set this equation `f(x) = k`. Clock signal is used to make this function, to syncronize, but you can desyncronize logic state from its rapresentation like `information` on monitor. For make this you should use a function generator. There is no only one method to manifestate same information, depends by function, not only by electronic state logic combination

Comment: Look about side channel attacks http://www.tau.ac.il/~tromer/papers/cache-joc-20090619.pdf